# Does creating WAR file using zip command affect the performance of my web application?

Tags: java, war, zsh

I have this WAR file that I need to deploy using BladeLogic Server Automation and then edit some XML files inside the WAR file.
My plan is to extract the WAR file using unzip command, then edit the XML files, and recreate WAR file with zip command.
So I write it in NSH Script (some kind of ZSH), but I notice that the size of my WAR file is reduced by 22 KB.
The question is, will this affect the performance of my web application?
Thank you.

Edit:

I solved it with -u command. Instead of creating new WAR file, I update the existing WAR file. The result has the same size as the original file. Thank you everyone for answering my question.

Comment: By default war file are not compressed. You probably compress your. It will slow down first start, but shouldn't affect application performance.

Comment: @talex thank you for your reply. Is there any way I can disable compression in zip command?

Comment: Try `-Z store`. or `-0` (zero).

Comment: I've tried the -0, but it only makes my file larger. But thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly unlikely. You might have used a better compression scheme which can result in slightly slower unpacking but this incurs a negligible one-off cost only.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any way I can disable compression in zip command?

Comment: Use the -0 switch to disable compression. E.g. `zip -r -0 my.zip files/`

Comment: If I use -0, my file grows by 2MB. So I solved it by using -u. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The reason of change in size can be accounted to metadata changes/byte code changes while packing/unpacking. This does not have an impact on the web application as long there are no changes in the source code or class path verisons

Comment: Thank you for your reply